# How to get reference of TextInput which define in static Navigation Options?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am facing problem getting reference of TextInput which is defined in static navigationOptions, it's that any way to do it in React Native? i am sharing some code here so you better know about my questions.

```
export default class SearchClass extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
    let headerTitle = (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <TextInput
                style={{ flex: 1, height: 30 }}
                placeholder='Search'
                keyboardType='default'
                returnKeyType='search'
                underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                onChangeText={text => params.onChangeText(text)}
                onSubmitEditing={(event) => { params.onSearchButton()    
                 }}
            />
        </View>
    );

    return { headerTitle };
  };

 componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
        onChangeText: this.__onChangeSearchText,
        onSearchButton: this.__onSearchButtonPress
    });
  }

__onSearchButtonPress = () => {
    // clear the text of TextInput
    // for that i need reference here of TextInput
    this.mySearchBox.clear();
 }

}
```

_onSearchButtonPress i need to clear the text of TextInput, for that i need reference of that TextInput which is define in navigationOptions ?
does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I've added a static variable inside class

```
static textField = null;
```

and then assign it inside `navigationOptions`

```
<TextInput
  ref={(ref) => YourClass.textField = ref}
    ...
```

then when I need to pass events (not sure if that's the best way) I either do a `pubsub-js` listener and publish event or I forward events - both ways explained with code bellow.

```
<TextInput
  ref={(ref) => YourClass.textField = ref}
  onChangeText={(text) => {
    YourClass.textField.onChangeText(text);
//    PubSub.publish(Constants.FIELD_DID_CHANGE, [text,]);
  }}
```

then when `didFocus` -- viewDidAppear equivalent

```
let textField = YourClass.textField;
textField.onChangeText = (text) => this._textFieldDidChange(text);
```

or register `PubSub` object in `componentDidMount`

```
// this.textFieldDidChangeListener = PubSub.subscribe(Constants.FIELD_DID_CHANGE, (msg, data) => this._textFieldDidChange(data));
```